# Joomla 3.10 won't work after they upgraded MariaDB on the server - Errors loading module Table 'joom_modules_menu' doesn't exist; field_values error

Tags: joomla, mariadb

Yesterday my site suddenly stopped working and after investigating I found out that Midphase upgraded the PHP to 8.1 and MariaDB (says from 10.3 to 10.5). I got them to roll back PHP to 7.4 for the time being, although it sounds like it was already on 7.4, which is good as they couldn't go back further.

My live site is on 3.10.1 (http://www.scifivision.com) and after running an upgrade on a backup, assuming I did it right I have a version on 3.10.11. (http://www.thejfiles.com/sfv2023). Both are giving me the same errors other than the database name is different.

The frontend gives me white page with the error "1146 - Table 'thejrub4_joomfin.joom_fields_values' doesn't exist" and backend gives me a warning "Error loading module Table 'thejrub4_joomfin.joom_modules_menu' doesn't exist" and it lets me log in but I can't do anything.

Just wanted to mention, in case it's relevant, I have an earlier backup (I'm at the point if anything is fixed I'll be happy) that is also giving me two warnings:

session_name(): Session name cannot be changed after headers have already been sent in /home/thejrub4/public_html/sfvclon/libraries/joomla/session/handler/native.php on line 128

ession_cache_limiter(): Session cache limiter cannot be changed after headers have already been sent in /home/thejrub4/public_html/sfvclon/libraries/joomla/session/handler/native.php on line 235
Error: Failed to start application: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "/home/thejrub4/public_html/sfvclon/libraries/vendor/joomla/input/src/Input.php" at line 41.

Since I am not seeing them on the newer backup, I'm assuming that is probably not the issue and was something I previously fixed, as I do have maximum on for debug

I have used forum post assistance for joomla.org if that helps and I will post the code below. This is for the 3.10.11 install, as the FPA wouldn't work on the older one. It says it should work without any issues, but clearly that's not true. I didn't know if that would help on this forum, but if you need it please let me know.

Comment: have you tried to repair the database?

Comment: @nbk If you mean the check/repair function within cpanel, yes I tried that right away and it said it was okay.